# Getting Code 3 Error: In KmsWrappedCryptoKey

Tags: google-cloud-dlp

getting the following error while trying to follow sample code to generate surrogate hash by setting cryptoHashConfig

```
{ Error: In KmsWrappedCryptoKey
    at Http2CallStream.call.on (/home/stoyak/Aritzia/dlp_api/node_modules/@google-cloud/dlp/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:103:45)
    at Http2CallStream.emit (events.js:187:15)
    at Http2CallStream.endCall (/home/stoyak/Aritzia/dlp_api/node_modules/@google-cloud/dlp/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:74:18)
    at handlingTrailers (/home/stoyak/Aritzia/dlp_api/node_modules/@google-cloud/dlp/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:163:18)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
  code: 3,
  details: 'In KmsWrappedCryptoKey',
  metadata: Metadata { internalRepr: Map {} },
  note:
   'Exception occurred in retry method that was not classified as transient' }
```

And here is the request that was used

```
{
   "parent":"projects/XXXX",
   "item":{
      "value":"XXXXXXXX"
   },
   "deidentifyConfig":{
      "infoTypeTransformations":{
         "transformations":[
            {
               "primitiveTransformation":{
                  "cryptoHashConfig":{
                     "cryptoKey":{
                        "kmsWrapped":{
                           "wrappedKey":"CiQAnHQoiec0s1myvgJiQf+NjFKQ1MxzN2s+v/Jq74ek3tqhnRoSMAAEfzpfTLYI6jaMSRN4J8Q6wOZ0glgNF9UR9N+HxY+dhyTiggHwVQRnbrNnKU9MUw==",
                           "cryptoKeyName":"projects/XXXX/locations/global/keyRings/XXX/cryptoKeys/XXX"
                        }
                     },
                     "commonAlphabet":"ALPHA_NUMERIC"
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: `commonAlphabet` isn't a field in `cryptoHashConfig` - the only field is `cryptoKey`. https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/reference/rest/v2/organizations.deidentifyTemplates#cryptohashconfig
What happens if you remove `commonAlphabet` from the request?

Comment: Actually, that was me trying to see if I am missing anything. It would be the same result. I've also tried to see if the KMS part could be an issue, by pointing to a different crypto Key or wrappedKey. But these are properly handled and API responded with proper messages, so it appears that KMS part of unwrapping the key works.

Answer (score 1):

Code 3 is an invalid input exception. My guess if if you inspect the http response you'll get a better tip as to what is wrong.

What you are looking for is the error response that looks like this

{
 "error": {
  "code": 400,
  "message": "The item has a mistake......",
  "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
 }
}

To rule out error handling in the client library, do you mind trying the same call via the Api Explorer? https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/dlp/v2/dlp.projects.content.deidentify